# Increase smtp connections in Exim4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, smtp, exim4

We are using Ubuntu 14 server with exim4 but I am running into an issue in which it is failing while sending out multiple emails.  I know in the the previous exim there was the setting "smtp_accept_max" which could be increased but the configurations in exim4 are vastly different.  Any guidance on how to increase the default limit would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, it is now in

```
/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/02_exim4-config_options
```